# Setting the size of an Imageview in a dynamic Linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am dynamically creating a linearlayout and adding some imageviews and textviews to it.

Code

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);

for(int i =0;i<ns;i++){
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100,50));

    llay.addView(tv);
    llay.addView(iv);
}
```

On running the application

1st device : The imageviews are of appropriate size.

2nd device : the imageviews are too small.

Is there any way, I can get away with setting the size of the imageview explicity so that it becomes device independent?

Answer (score 2):

Try This....

If your app for diff size density use display height/width instead of fix value.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      int height = display.getHeight()/10;
      int width = display.getWidth()/5;

ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);

for(int i =0;i<ns;i++){
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height,0));

    llay.addView(tv);
    llay.addView(iv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's recommend to use dp instead of px.

For more information about dp vs px you can visit [Support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

In your case, you set the value in pixels. If you want to work with dp you can use the following:

```
float x = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Can u please elaborate, how can that be applied to my situation?

Comment: your current `100` is in pixel, you should change it into dp with that provided method.